# Python 2 OpenCV 2 - Convex Hull to close an open Canny Edge?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv

I'm creating a Python program that will take an image (photo of a bed), then run Canny Edge detection, then run a Convex Hull Contour Detection in order to figure out where the bed is.

Here is my image (pardon the ugly Photoshop Job)

[image: bed]

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import glob
import cv2
import sys

from pyimagesearch import imutils
from skimage import exposure


def auto_canny(image, sigma = 0.35):
    # compute the mediam of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) *v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

    # return edged image
    return edged

image = cv2.imread("bed_cv.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

wide = auto_canny(blurred, 0.35)
tight = auto_canny(blurred, 0.95)
auto = auto_canny(blurred)



cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Edges", tight)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

What we basically do here is we get the image, turn in to gray, blur it, then run canny edge detection.

Here is the output I get so far:

[image: Output]

What I want to do next is to run a Convex Hull Contour Detection so the top right corner of the bed will be closed off, and hopefully, get a nice rectangle estimation of where the bed is.

Right now I'm stuck mainly because I'm not sure how to use the hull points? I tried something like:

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnts, returnPoints = False)
```

But I didn't know what to do after.

My main lead right now is [this post from the opencv website](http://answers.opencv.org/question/74777/how-to-use-approxpolydp-to-close-contours/). It's exactly what I need. His initial output were two sets of edges that were disconnected and the answer managed to connect them. However, I am rather rusty with my C++ and I'm not sure how to convert the C++ code into Python. And I think that if I get a Python version of this, my problem is basically solved.

Comment: [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html). Let me know if you want it coded, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @RickM. Would you kindly code it out? I'd like to see it used for my case.

Comment: Sure. I will do it over the weekend.

Comment: @RickM. still no code ahahahaha

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using OpenCV only, worked great for me:

```
mask = cv2.Canny(gray, lowerThresh, upperTresh)
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, cnt in enumerate(cnts):
    cnts[i] = cv2.convexHull(cnts[i])
```

Hope it helps!